# Problema al mostrar caracteres especiales JAVA-Kdb

Tags: java, string, jsp

Extraigo los datos de una BBDD a través de un conector, pero a la hora de mostrármelos en una lista en un jsp me los muestra así:

[image: Así me muestra los datos]

¿Como puedo formatear los Strings al sacarlos o que puedo hacer para que me los muestre con sus tildes y las ñ??

Gracias.

Con este código extraigo:

```
con = new c(HOST, PORT, USER_PASS);

        rs = (c.Flip) con.k(query);

        for(int fila = 1; fila < con.n(rs.y[0]); fila++){
            for(int col = 0; col < rs.x.length; col++){
                if(con.at(rs.y[col], fila)!=null){       
                   dataStr = con.at(rs.y[col], fila).toString(); 

                }

                if(dataStr!=null){
                    if(!dataStr.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
                        muni.setName(dataStr);                            
                    } else if (!dataStr.contains("-")){
                        muni.setNhab(dataStr);
                        data = data + Integer.valueOf(dataStr);
                        if(selectedMuni.contains(muni.getName())){
                            muni.setBool("true");
                        } else {
                            muni.setBool("false");
                        }
                    } 

                }  
            }
            result.add(muni);
```

Con este código muestro:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

```
<c:forEach var="municipio" items="${requestScope.municipios}">
<option value="${municipio.name}" <c:if test="${municipio.bool eq 'true'}">selected</c:if>>${municipio.name}</option>`<c:forEach var="municipio" items="${requestScope.municipios}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende mucho del sistema gestor de bases de datos (MySQL, Oracle, PostegreSQL, por nombrar algunos) que estés utilizando y de como hallas definido el campo que estás consultando.

En principio Java no tiene problema en representar en tildes y `ñ`s porque la clase String trabaja con una codificación UTF-16 como dice en la [API de Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which
>   supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs (see the
>   section Unicode Character Representations in the Character class for
>   more information). Index values refer to char code units, so a
>   supplementary character uses two positions in a String.

Pero para que se vea mejor el problema sería bueno que compartieras el código donde consultas de la base de datos y donde muestras.

Para solucionar este tipo de errores me parece interesante el método que se propone en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/3958), aunque sea PHP y no Java creo que se pueden extraer la ideas más importantes.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que parece, tu modo de presentación de datos deberían ser JSPs.

Por tanto, deberías decir a tus páginas que estás codificándolas como UTF-16.

Como dicen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723499/3617531) para que aparezcan las páginas JSP con esa codificación, debes añadirles:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-16" %>
```

Por otra parte, deberás configurar también tu base de datos con el mismo encoding para evitar problemas.